# pass link value to bean

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts-1

I have a JSP file with links like below:

```
<a href="links.do?method=homeAdmin">
<a href="links.do?method=signUp">
```

And I have an action class `LinkAction.java`:

```
public class LinkAction extends org.apache.struts.action.Action {

    public ActionForward signUp(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        return mapping.findForward("signUp");
    }
    public ActionForward homeAdmin(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        return mapping.findForward("homeAdmin");
    }
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't work. But when I change it to something like this, it works only for the `signUp` action.

```
public class LinkAction extends org.apache.struts.action.Action {

    @Override
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        return mapping.findForward("signUp");
    }

}
```

I also tried changing it to

```
public class LinkAction extends DispatchAction { ... }
```

Here is my `struts-config.xml`

```
<action input="/index.jsp"
        name="signUp" 
        path="/links" 
        scope="session" 
        type="Actions.LinkAction">
   <forward name="signUp" path="/signUp.jsp"/>
   <forward name="homeAdmin" path="/homeAdmin.jsp"/>
</action>
```

I want to use this single action file for all the links in my web page. How do I do it?

Comment: Can you share the action definition in your `struts-config.xml`?.

Comment: I think that you just need to add something in the `struts-config.xml` and use an action extending the class  `org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `parameter="method"`. This identify the request parameter containing the method name.

If you had the next action class:

```
package actions;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction;

public class LinkAction extends DispatchAction {

    public ActionForward signUp(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        return mapping.findForward("signUp");
    }

    public ActionForward homeAdmin(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        return mapping.findForward("homeAdmin");
    }
}
```

You will need the following configuration in the `struts-config.xml` file:

```
<form-beans>
    <form-bean name="SignUpForm" type="org.apache.struts.action.DynaActionForm">
        <form-property name="fname" type="java.lang.String" />
        <form-property name="lname" type="java.lang.String" />
        <form-property name="usr" type="java.lang.String" />
        <form-property name="pwd" type="java.lang.String" />
    </form-bean>
</form-beans>
<action-mappings>
    <action path="/links"
            type="actions.LinkAction"
            name="SignUpForm"
            input="/index.jsp"
            parameter="method"
            scope="session">
       <forward name="signUp" path="/signUp.jsp"/>
       <forward name="homeAdmin" path="/homeAdmin.jsp"/>
    </action>
</action-mappings>
```

See also [`org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction`](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.3.x/struts-extras/apidocs/org/apache/struts/actions/DispatchAction.html).

Comment: Is it possible for me to add multiple inputs in the same action in struts config? Cause i have links from multiple pages using the same LinkAction.java file.

Comment: And yes adding the parameter="method" in struts config worked.

Comment: The `input` attribute is used in validation errors and when you `return mapping.getInputForward();` for _forward_ to the input page. With simple links, you can use `html:link` tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
Struts1 always calls execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
```

method for processing the request. You can try getting request `parameter('method')` in the `execute()` method and proxy it to homeAdmin or signUp based on its value.

Answer (score 1):

According to me what i got your question,

1.) is there any way, through one action class, you can handle the multiple task, like : your both of method could work.

```
public ActionForward signUp(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws Exception {

return mapping.findForward("signUp");
}

public ActionForward homeAdmin(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws Exception {

return mapping.findForward("homeAdmin");
}
```

if it is correct then you should go for another type of Action i.e. DispatchAction, because it provide an ability to write more than one method.

for details :

```
public class LanguageSelectAction extends DispatchAction{

public ActionForward chinese(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,
    HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
throws Exception {

    request.getSession().setAttribute(
            Globals.LOCALE_KEY, Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE);

    return mapping.findForward("provide");
}

public ActionForward english(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,
    HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
throws Exception {

    request.getSession().setAttribute(
            Globals.LOCALE_KEY, Locale.ENGLISH);

    return mapping.findForward("success");
}

public ActionForward german(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,
    HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
throws Exception {

    request.getSession().setAttribute(
            Globals.LOCALE_KEY, Locale.GERMAN);

    return mapping.findForward("success");
}

public ActionForward france(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,
    HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
throws Exception {

    request.getSession().setAttribute(
            Globals.LOCALE_KEY, Locale.FRANCE);

    return mapping.findForward("success");
}
```

}

you can get the detailed [here](http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-dispatchaction-example/)

Comment: the return mapping.findForward() returns the same string in every method. I want to forward different string according to the method I call.

Comment: @Ankit in web.xml, all ready you are mapping your action, now if you see the < forward="provide" path="/requiredpage.jsp"/>, then it is saying that you are returning "provide" in place of "success" string. <action-mappings>
  <action input="/yourpage.jsp" parameter="method" name="yourform" 
    path="/yourAction" scope="session/request" type="yourpackage.youraction">
    <forward name="provide" path="/requiredpage.jsp" />
</action>

Answer (score 1):

As piyush explained above do it with extending your action class with DispatchAction click http://struts.apache.org/release/1.3.x/struts-extras/apidocs/org/apache/struts/actions/DispatchAction.html

and configuration in your config file should be something like this

```
<action-mappings>
  <action input="/yourpage.jsp" parameter="method" name="yourform" 
    path="/yourAction" scope="session/request" type="yourpackage.youraction">
    <forward name="signup" path="/yourpage.jsp" />
</action>
```